# create index or each month in array for the specific time interval

Tags: python, pandas

What I am trying to do is that I have beginning and end of an interval and want to create an index for each month.

I'm using `pandas`, but I should calculate the number of month using the following approach:

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.period_range('2014-04', periods=<number-of-month>, freq='M')
```

Is there any way to create it automatically, I mean for example give it two arguments as beginning and end interval and then it creates an index for each month; in other words I mean:

pseudo-code:

```py
pd.period_range(start='2014-04', end='2014-07', freq='M')
```

Expected output for the above pseudo-code is [0, 0, 0] because there are 3 month from 2014-04 to 2014-07.

Expected DataFrame to implement and want to access them by index:

```py
index     date     count
0       2014-04      0
1       2014-05      0
2       2014-06      0
```

At first the array place zero for all of the indices and I call them count. I want to increment the count column using date. for example:

```py
a = pd.period_range(start='2014-04', end='2014-07', freq='M')
a['2014-04'] += 1
```

```
index     date     count
0       2014-04      1
1       2014-05      0
2       2014-06      0
```

How can I implement it?

Comment: Can you show your output dataframe? How should it look like?

Comment: Do you want `pd.date_range(start='2014-04', end='2019-08', freq="M")`?

Comment: @min2bro added!

Comment: @Chris exactly!

Comment: @min2bro The problem defined explicitly and edited , I would be thankful if you could give me upvote

Comment: @Chris The problem defined explicitly and edited , I would be thankful if you could give me upvote

Comment: What do you mean by _increment the count_? Can you post the _final_ expected output?

Comment: @MostafaGhadimi I'm still not clear what is the expected output. As chris mentioned what do you mean by increment the count? Can you give a short and simple example with expected output please

Comment: @min2bro I have edited the post again :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need create `PeriodIndex` by `period_range` and then for add `1` to column `counter` use `loc`:

```
a = pd.period_range(start='2014-04', end='2014-07', freq='M')

df = pd.DataFrame({'count':0}, index=a)

df.loc['2014-04', 'count'] += 1
print (df)
         count
2014-04      1
2014-05      0
2014-06      0
2014-07      0
```

Solution with `Series`:

```
a = pd.period_range(start='2014-04', end='2014-07', freq='M')

s = pd.Series(0, index=a)

s['2014-04'] += 1
print (s)
2014-04    1
2014-05    0
2014-06    0
2014-07    0
Freq: M, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, make `pandas.Series` with `index = pd.date_range(...)`:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(0, index=pd.date_range(start='2014-04', end='2019-08', freq="M"))
s['2014-04'] += 1
s.head()
```

Output:

```
2014-04-30    1
2014-05-31    0
2014-06-30    0
2014-07-31    0
2014-08-31    0
Freq: M, dtype: int64
```

Comment: @jezrael IIUC, OP wants to 1. make monthly range, 2. use it to access some specific month and do some calculation. first part is partially based on the comment I made. Let me know if i'm misunderstood :)

Comment: yes, but period_range here is perfectly fine... Added answer.

Comment: @jezrael Ah that's true. I've got too accustomed to using `date_range`. My bad :P

Comment: Ya, I was surprised, so ask ;)

Comment: Thank you Chris. You helped me a lot <3